# After repairing pcv pipes on my water line I have very little water pressure. 1/2 pvc pipe ; no leaks just no pressure

Tags: plumbing, pvc

I repaired pvc pipe with new fittings ; no leaks ; but I now have no water pressure. 1/2 in pipe

Comment: This question is in need of additional information.  Why did you repair to begin with?  A photo of what you're dealing with would be helpful.  Beyond that, you have a blockage somewhere.  Find it and fix it.

Comment: Where is the repair related to the main valve and the other items in the house? Is everything in your house affected?

Comment: Hi, we could use a lot more details, such as whether you're running off a pump or municipal water.   And remember - no leaks doesn't mean no blockage.